# Сервер Windows 10

Tags: windows, сервер, сеть

Вопрос состоит в следующем: каким образом я могу настроить централизованную систему 40 компьютеров БЕЗ жестких дисков в них самих? 
 Теперь что касается конкретики: есть 40 компьютеров на Windows, их нужно проводами подключить к некому серверу, который так же изначально нужно собрать, и настроить доступ таким образом, чтобы жестких дисков вообще не было в самих блоках, либо чтобы на них не располагалось информации, а все лежало в серверной части, в условном "подвале". Каким образом я могу это сделать, какие мне нужны будут инструменты, хабы, системы, и как это вообще будет называться, чтобы я мог искать информацию в сети, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Ха, вам нужно 40 серверов (не 40 домашних пк) с контролером Smart Array для шифрования данных, и хранения сессий, пакетов.
И да игровые залы я так понимаю вне закона в Вашей стране, при этом вы хотите получить информацию здесь (бесплатно) , успехов .

Comment: Ключевые слова для поиска: pxe, dhcp, тонкий клиент, thin client, tftp, Network File System, ISCSI, RAID Более развёрнутый ответ будет содержать уже краткую инструкцию как настраивать всё "от и до". Большой стек технологий на самом деле.

Comment: Нет, все законно, подвал - условное место, где будет стоять главный сервер, а так хоть на крыше. Никаких игровых залов, офисные программы, просто необходимо всю информацию держать не в самих компьютерах, а в одном месте, чтобы при краже первых никакой информации не досталось

Comment: Вам нужны специалисты - парочка программистов и специалист по криптографии, которые Вам напишут серверную часть, и клиент для сотрудников ( без возможности копирования и сохранения данных локально) а как вы подключите сервер - машины вообще без разницы.

Comment: @DigitalCore, а как ты интересно зашифруешь то, что выдаётся на экран, который можно отснять камерой смартфона? Задача - более чем стандартная, надо просто создать сервер и тонких клиентов. Шифрование не нужно.

Comment: @donRumata  не верно, вот стану я в цепь этого самого кабеля идущего к серверу, в реалиях нашего времени мне даже резать его не придётся, да не нужно шифрование.